# Big-O running time of sorting vs inserting

Tags: arrays, sorting, insert, runtime, big-o

So if you use quick sort to sort an array you can do it in O(nlogn) using quicksort and then once you sort it, you can insert new elements into the array in O(logn) with a binary-search-esque algorithm.

My question is, is there a way to prove that if you can insert into a sorted array in O(logn) time, then that means that the sorting algorithm would have had to be at least O(nlogn)?

In other words, is there a relationship between the two algorithms' running times?

Comment: But an O(n^2) algorithm is worse than O(nlogn), and I was asking if the original sort could at a minimum be O(nlogn) knowing the insertion time. So it wouldn't matter if you can sort in O(n^2) or O(n^3).

Comment: "you can insert new elements into the array in O(logn) with a binary-search-esque algorithm.", actually, you can't, since on insert you would have to move on average `O(n)` array elements.

Comment: @DanielFischer false: inserting in a linked list is O(1). I know it's pretty specific, but not always true :).

Comment: @Destrictor Huh? Nobody talked about inserting into linked lists. (Which is only O(1) when you have a pointer to the place you want to insert after, if you need to find the place, it's O(how far you need to go).)

Answer (score 1):

No: it would be possible to use bubblesort (O(n²)) to sort the array. After that, it would still be possible to use the same algorithm to insert at O(log(n)) time.

Comment: user is talking about **atleast** O(nlogn)

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia the user's last sentence specifically asks about the relationship between the two algorithms running times. One could also use a slower algorithm to insert (iterating over array > insert before the first location that's bigger) with O(n), but you'd still be able to use a quicksort (n log(n)) or a bubblesort (O(n²)). This obviously indicates that there's no relationship between the sorting algorithm and the inserting algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the fact that insertion which maintains order is O(log n) means that a sort operation can be performed in O(n log n) simply by inserting each element in turn into the array. This however is probably the opposite of what you're really asking; it proves that there is an O(n log n) sort, but doesn't disprove the possibility of a faster sort.

Answer (score 0):

First off, some sorting algorithms, which require special conditions, have a potentially lower time complexity. For instance [Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) which has complexity of O(n+k) (where k is the highest number in the array) or [Radix Sort](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort&ei=vmuiUN7-I-ei0QX98YHQAg&usg=AFQjCNGfaterKCZkUX6qcwxj09zmb_6HVQ) with the complexity of O(n*k) (where k is the maximal number of digits in the arrays elements).
The bound of O(nlogn) applies to **comparison algorithms**.

Second, to answer the question, no (sadly). The relation between insertion and sorting is the other way around, just like davmac said.

The reason that the lower bound on comparison is that you require at least nlogn comparisons to find the right order. See [This wiki page on comparison sort algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Lower_bound_for_the_average_number_of_comparisons) for more details. Just note that the prof has nothing to do with insertion (the prof does not assume any insertions actually).